# Passing values and storing in database without using form in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a very basic car rental management website using nodejs,express and mongodb ,i need some help on how to pass a value,store it in the database and display it in the redirected page without using a form. eg.select car using buttons ,select date and display it in next page for multiple orders(order history) Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value through your URL or by request body.
At server.js
you can get it by using req.params or req.body followed by name

Comment: Thats helpful,but can you instruct me on how i can store the parameter values to the database as well? –

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think that maybe you can try the query params or body params that express have for. With that just need to pass the params in the url or body in the request to the API and use the params as you wish.

You can see something here

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Thats helpful,but can you instruct me on how i can store the parameter values to the database as well?